# What are the resonance structures of methyl azide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

I am supposed to construct the major resonance structures of methyl azide, $\ce{CH3N3}$. I know that in compounds such as the carbonate anion $\ce{CO3^2-}$, resonance can be depicted by interconverting single and double bonds:

[image: Resonance structures of carbonate anion]

Is something similar happening with methyl azide but with nitrogens instead of oxygens? e.g.

[image: (Incorrect) resonance structures of methyl azide]

Comment: You have the wrong structural isomer.

Comment: Think about the azide again. Hint: Sodium azide ($\ce{NaN3}$ hydrolyzes to $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{N3-}$. At the moment, your methyl azide looks like a disfigured guanidine ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your Y-shaped structures somewhat resemble guanidine, $\ce{HN=C(NH2)2}$. For an exercise on resonance structures, its protonated form, the guanidinium cation, would be an interesting case and you might want to give it a try too.

Methyl azide, however, looks completely different.

1. As the name suggests, there should be a methyl group, $\ce{CH3}$, and an azide group.
2. Draw the linear azide anion, $\ce{N3-}$.

   > [image: azide anion]
3. Where would a "$\ce{CH3+}$" go?
   Is methyl azide, $\ce{CH3N3}$, a linear molecule?
4. Draw the resonance structures for methyl azide.

   > [image: methyl azide]

Comment: [Structure](https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.19.9.860) was determined in 1933 by Brockway and Pauling. The bond distance of the terminal two nitrogen atoms is very close to that in dinitrogen.